# glassfish 3.1 system properties deployment

Tags: deployment, maven, glassfish, system-properties

I had a log4j error ([see here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload)) and the suggested fix worked. I set the `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES` system property to false in the console with asadmin.

As I am working with maven in a project using glassfish 3.1 I have to insert this fix in my code somewhere to make it run for everybody. I figured out this can be done with the maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin as a command. So i wrote this code and put it in my `pom.xml`:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
    <commands>
     <command>create-system-properties org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false</command>
    </commands>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But the server will not create the system property. What am I missing here?
Is there another way to realize this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your link "see here" seems to be broke.

Comment: works for me. but here it is again: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload

Comment: Embedded Glassfish plugin does what it says by it name - configures embedded Glassfish you can run as a part of your integration test. Change of system properties is not deployable.